# Find the column Sum of table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to this forum. I need to get the product of rows and sum of columns.Row product is ok now.but it seems very difficult to find the column sum
Here is the LInk
http://jsfiddle.net/Mpayr/10/
Please help me to solve this??

Comment: its working for me if i give the id name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've update your codes here http://jsfiddle.net/bondythegreat/dm4AZ/1/

Answer (score 4):

Try using classes for rows and sum iteratively over the class:

```
<table>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Second</th>
    <th>Third</th>
    <th>SUM</th>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="row1 column1" value = "100"/></td>
        <td><input class="row1 column2" value = "100"/></td>
        <td><input class="row1 column3" value = "100"/></td>
        <td class="total">300</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><input class="row2 column1" value = "200"/></td>
        <td><input class="row2 column2" value = "200"/></td>
        <td><input class="row2 column3" value = "200"/></td>
        <td class="total">600</td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td>Sum of Column(SUM)</td><td><input name="result" id="result"></td></tr>
</table>
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).keyup(function(){ 
        var sum = 0;
        var column2 = $('.column2')
        jQuery.each(column2,function(number){
            sum += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $('#result').val(sum);
    });
})
```

`.each` then allows you to sum over all the inputs with this class. Use this approach for each of  the columns and rows.

Comment: Also, do you want the product or sum of the rows? If you want product you need to initialise at `sum=1` and iterate a multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for summation in both x and y pattern like row total & column total you can check my example [excel like sum jquery](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/10/excel-like-summation-using-jquery.html)