# How to set a total in a column in a table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic table with names and prices generated according to buttons in the website. I need to compute the total for this table.

```
<table id="countit">
 <tr>
   <th >name</th>
   <th >price</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td  id ="name"></td>       //this is dynamically generated through buttons
   <td id ="price" ></td>      //this is dynamically generated through buttons
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <th >total</th>
   <th id="grandtotal" ></th>   //total goes here
 </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it in Javascript, please?

Comment: You want to create table rows dynamically and add all prices and set that total price in <th id="grandtotal"> ?

Comment: i already did  the dynamic rows i just need the total price plz

Comment: Please share the button click function code, as we want to see how you are generating those rows. :)

Comment: If you are open to using jQuery, [there is a solution here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471801/find-the-column-sum-of-table-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Click here for Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTDTF/)

```
    <table id="countit" border="1">
 <tr>
   <th >name</th>
   <th >price</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td  id ="name">aaa</td>       
   <td name="price">10</td>      
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td  id ="name">bbb</td>       
   <td name="price">20</td>      
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td  id ="name">ccc</td>       
   <td name="price">30</td>      
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <th >total</th>
   <th id="grandtotal" ></th> 
 </tr>
</table>

<script>

    var tds = document.getElementsByName("price");

    var total = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<tds.length; i++)
    total += parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);

    document.getElementById('grandtotal').innerHTML=total;

</script>
```

Comment: NaN , it means not a number. Check your data and do the parsing properly.

Comment: I getting total correctly, check in fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/zTDTF/) link which I provided

Comment: @user3366530 you need to assure that only numeric characters are there in price column, other charcters(like alphabets, space, etc) will cause to get NaN exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tr>
  <td  id ="name"></td>       
  <td name ="price" ></td>      
 </tr>
```

If you are generating table rows from any back-end language then provide a common value to "name" attribute. Then from the javascript get these element using

```
var prices=getElementsByName('price'); 
for(i=0;i<prices.length;i++){
   total = total+parseInt(prices[i].innerHTML);
}
```

once you get the total you can set this value to any element.

```
document.getElementById('grandTotal').innerHTML = total;
```